# Aggregation function on Group by on multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation

```
WEEK    | CID | CUSTOMER_ID | L1
2017-04 | 12  | 1           | ABC
2017-04 | 13  | 1           | ABC
2017-04 | 13  | 1           | ABC
2017-04 | 16  | 1           | DFG
2017-04 | 15  | 2           | DFG
2017-14 | 14  | 1           | DFG
```

I have created a table by combining many databases (sample of the created table is above). I want the number of times each customer_id came in each week (such that like for `2017-04` week `customer_id 1` came in 3 times, we want to consider row 2 & 3 as same (so 1 count for that) and then row 1 and row 4 makes it 3 times.

So, output should be:

```
WEEK    | CUSTOMER_ID | COUNT(CUSTOMER_ID)
2017-04 | 1           | 3
2017-04 | 2           | 1
2017-14 | 1           | 1
```

I'm trying something in the following lines:

```
select
    week, customer_id, count(customer_id)
from
    table
group by 
    week, cid, customer_id, L1;
```

But, I want to confirm doing like this will it count rows 2 & 3 as one count or two counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `count(distinct)`:

```
select week, customer_id, count(distinct cid)
from table
group by week, customer_id;
```

Comment: I think count(distinct cid) is what I want, but just curious if I do group by week, customer_id, L1 instead of group by week, customer_id, will that make any difference?

Comment: @Arman . . . Based on your sample data, it would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT WEEK, 
       CUSTOMER_ID,
       COUNT( DISTINCT CID)
  FROM TABLE
GROUP BY WEEK,CUSTOMER_ID;
```